# How does one calculate the energy used depending on the velocity and air resistance of an object

Tags: forces, energy, velocity, drag

I'm in need of a equation that can tell me how much energy/work I need to move an object inside a low  air-pressure tube. The equation should (if possible) include drag, object velocity and mass.
If there isn't such a equation i would also be happy if you could show me a way how to get to the calculate the work/energy needed.

Thank you for you're time. If you have any questions about my issue please do ask.

Comment: At high Reynolds number, the drag force is usually modeled as: $F_D=\frac12 \rho v^2 C_A A$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assume that the object is moving in the opposite direction to that of the drag force.

If you know the magnitude of the drag force $F_{\rm drag}(t)$ and the speed of the object $v(t)$ then rate at which energy is being dissipated at a particular time $t$ is $F_{\rm drag}(t) \,v(t) $.

To evaluate the total energy dissipation from time $t_{\rm start}$ to time $t_{\rm finish}$ you will need to do an integration $\displaystyle \int_{t_{\rm start}}^{t_{\rm finish}} F_{\rm drag}(t) \,v(t)  \, dt$

Comment: *Assume that the object is moving in the opposite direction to that of the drag force.* Assume? Friction (here air drag) is **ALWAYS** in the opposite direction of motion.

Comment: @Gert I do not know why I wrote that sentence but on reflection you can have a moving fluid applying a frictional force on an object in the direction of motion of the object when the object is moving slower than the fluid.